# How I can navigate to another page and display user data?

Tags: php

I know how to fetch user data from database with the code below. Now I want to navigate to another page (using onclick) and to display this user data by id.  This would be like StackOverflow or Facebook, when you click on a photo or ID, and the site takes you to the user's profile page.

Here is my code so far:

```
  <?php
   $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
   $select = mysql_select_db("profile") or die(mysql_error());
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users order by id DESC");
   $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if($row['id'] !== $id){
             echo "<table id='suggest'><tr><td id='frienddata'><a href='http://localhost/profile/userprofile.php'>".$row['first'].' '. $row['last']."<a/></td><br></tr></table>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: add a GET parameter eg: userprofile.php?id=5

Comment: Can you give me more help please, where do I have to add GET?

Answer (score 3):

```html
$id = $_GET['id'];
if(!isset($id))
{
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
   $select = mysql_select_db("profile") or die(mysql_error());
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '"$id"'");
if(!$result) 
{
  die('user_not_found');
}
mysqli_fetch_row( $result );
echo "<table id='sugest'><tr><td id='frienddata'><a href='http://localhost/profile/userprofile.php'>".$row['first'].' '. $row['last']."<a/></td><br></tr></table>";
```

Comment: Im trying, it returning the following code: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\profile\uprofile.php on line 220

Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\profile\uprofile.php on line 221

Comment: could you show your uprofile.php file please ? and with number of line

Comment: Its long code, i have added css temporarily, I don't know how I can paste in notepad

Comment: so , how can I find your error on 221 line .  Maybe you'll just copy 221 th line and paste here

Comment: Udefined Index: id and undefined variable id......line217    $userid = $_GET['id']; ..........//line 221 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$id."'");

Comment: do you have column named  "id"  in your database ?

Comment: so , have you defined your id like userprofile.php?id=5 . Because For $_GET method will  get url path and compare it with database id

Answer (score 1):

suppose you are in a page before clicking on a user profile,the link should be some thing like this 'site.com/userprofile.php?id=5'.
now in userprofile.php:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if(!isset($id))
     die('user not found');
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$select = mysql_select_db("profile") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where id='".$id."'");
if (!$result) {
 die('user not found');
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo "<table id='sugest'><tr><td id='frienddata'><a href='http://localhost/profile/userprofile.php'>".$row['first'].' '. $row['last']."<a/></td><br></tr></table>";
```